# how to pass variables from php to flash but not allowed see it in browser

Tags: security, variables

Hi I try to pass some pin code from php to flash - as3 , but unfortunatly I use in php command : `echo pin='1234';` - if anyone will open link php will see this pin 1234

is there anyway pass this variables requested from flash in hidden way ?? like check in php who request this variables and only allowed it to swf on local server not any other file or from any other locations !????

thank you for any answers and ideas

Regards
Hubert

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no fully secure way to do this.

As the SWF is running on the client, even if you were able to devise a method or protocol so that only the swf could see the communications to the server, a hacker can use a memory debugger or some inspection tool to inspect what is being seen by the swf and get the pin.

Simply put, there is no secure way to do this. You should consider why the client requesting the pin through other means would be a problem. For example, if you implement some sort of authentication, then only the authorized user can request the pin, and it shouldn't matter how he requests it, because it is his own pin after all.

Comment: Thank you for answare, so it is any way to put in Action Script in swf that as not any of swf obfuscator will read it so he can find actually what file I try targeting on server ?

Comment: There simply no way to do that. You could set up a custom protocol between your swf and the server, but it can be easily by passed by capturing the raw packets using a network analyser like wireshark. So in other words, you can perhaps make things a bit harder for people trying to break your app, but you can only slow them down slightly.